GEKKO mixed integer optimization callback function with APOPT solver
I am trying to solve a simple mixed-integer optimization problem using GEKKO to evaluate whether it is suitable for my actual optimization task. Since my future problems will depend on adhering to constraints and integer conditions in each iteration, I need a workaround for a callback function in GEKKO. Everything I have tried so far has not worked for mixed-integer optimization.
To address this, I am examining problem HS71 from the GEKKO documentation with the addition of an integer specification. I discovered that when using the code from the GEKKO documentation, it is necessary to set the solver to APOPT to enhance mixed-integer optimization
Additionally, I referred to Get variable values at each iteration of GEKKO optimization to get ideas on how to improvise a call-back function here.
While sticking to floats only, the following code is working just fine:
from gekko import GEKKO

max_iter=0
while True:

    #Initialize Model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.options.SOLVER=1 # 1=APOPT, 2=BPOPT, 3=IPOPT

    #define parameter
    eq = m.Param(value=40)

    #initialize variables
    x1 = m.Var(1, lb=1, ub=5, integer=False)
    x2 = m.Var(5, lb=1, ub=5, integer=False)
    x3 = m.Var(5, lb=1, ub=5, integer=False)
    x4 = m.Var(1, lb=1, ub=5, integer=False)

    #Equations
    m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
    m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==eq)

    #Objective
    m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)

    #Set global options
    m.options.MAX_ITER = max_iter
    m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

    #Solve simulation
    m.solve(disp=False, debug=0)
    print(max_iter,x1.value, x2.value, x3.value, x4.value ,m.options.OBJFCNVAL)

    if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
        break # break loop with successful solution
    else:
        max_iter += 1 # increment maximum iterations

#Results
print('')
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))
print(m.options.OBJFCNVAL)

Since I did not study programming in python, I stuck to an easier comprehensible coding of the problem.
Using floats, it results in 6 iterations displayed which corresponds to the GEKKO disp number of iteration. One can also see changes in each iteration.
1 [1.0] [4.3960512908] [4.3243028722] [1.2928862199] 16.891614822
2 [1.0] [4.804484123] [3.8120497138] [1.3481405759] 16.776489179
3 [1.0] [4.7437502313] [3.8210281858] [1.3788731099] 17.009643947
4 [1.0] [4.7429972536] [3.8211532601] [1.3794077293] 17.014016403
5 [1.0] [4.743000147] [3.8211493182] [1.3794083853] 17.014017289
6 [1.0] [4.742999637] [3.8211499845] [1.3794082931] 17.014017289

Results
x1: [1.0]
x2: [4.742999637]
x3: [3.8211499845]
x4: [1.3794082931]
17.014017289

Once I restrict any variable to integer, the callback is not working. I get 5 identical rows and in the last one, the optimized values are shown (here with x1 set as integer):
1 [1.0] [5.0] [5.0] [1.0] 16.0
2 [1.0] [5.0] [5.0] [1.0] 16.0
3 [1.0] [5.0] [5.0] [1.0] 16.0
4 [1.0] [5.0] [5.0] [1.0] 16.0
5 [1.0] [5.0] [5.0] [1.0] 16.0
6 [1.0] [4.742999637] [3.8211499845] [1.3794082931] 17.014017289

Results
x1: [1.0]
x2: [4.742999637]
x3: [3.8211499845]
x4: [1.3794082931]
17.014017289

I'd expect variations in each row and probably also a different number of iterations. I don't understand the root cause of this malfunction, probably because I don't have knowledge about how GEKKO and APOPT are working internally. Maybe one of you can help me out.
PS: Prior to this method I tried a workaround I used with scipy.optimize -> giving the objective function as >>> def [...] return <<< and printing the parameters in there. Apparently that didn't work either.

Gekko compiles the optimization problem into byte-code before giving it to the optimizer. Callbacks aren't allowed in Gekko because the optimization problem is self-contained as an APM file gk0_model.apm in the run directory m._path that can be accessed with
m.open_folder()

One way around this issue is to retrieve the unconverged solution with debug=0 in m.solve(disp=False, debug=0) and then restart the optimization problem again from those new updated guess values. When integer values are introduced, only the initial guesses are returned if the problem is unconverged because of the branch and bound algorithm.

Thank you very much for your answer.
That means in fact, once integers are introduced, the debug method fails as workaround and there is no known method for callbacks. Is it?

Callbacks are generally used as a way to insert external information such as logic or use a black box model. This is not supported by Gekko because the optimization problem must be recompiled each time it is stopped. As a bit of background, Mixed Integer problems don't report the failed solution with 1-5 max iterations for this problem because they are reporting the results of the branch and bound algorithm that operates in an outer loop from the Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solve. When it is just an NLP solution (no integers) then those iteration intermediate results are shown.
